# Visual Studio : Project doesn't include recent changes made

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation

My program written in vb.net doesn't show any changes made. It just successfully compile/clean/build. On runtime nothing is changed.

I have tried re installing the whole VS 2010, deleted bin and obj folders. Changing the options in the Tools and Build tabs. Nothing worked.

It just compiles successfully and nothing is ever changed.

Design Time:
[image]

Run Time:
[image]

Comment: Maybe, but just maybe, it could be **useful to see your code** to help you figure out why it doesn't affect anything... so please edit your post and include your code. Further more, read : http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @R3uK There's no code involved in this i believe. I just added a button and a label. On runtime nothing is shown just previous version (without the added controls) on design time its clearly there.